# Swift Toast not working in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? My code is written exactly the same as it is specified in the documentation but I am getting an error saying "use of unresolved identifier ToastStyle"

```
func showToast() {
    let style = ToastStyle()
    style.messageColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.makeToast("Product added successfully!", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom, style: style)
}

@IBAction func saveProduct(_ sender: AnyObject) {       
    self.showToast()
}
```

Comment: did you import that framework to your project

Comment: Yes, in this order:
1) Added dependency to my Procfile
2) Ran "pod install"
3) Added "import Toast_Swift" to my ViewController

Comment: I am now getting error saying "cannon load underlying module for Toast_Swift"

Comment: Instead of toast, you can use alert action with "OK".

Comment: Try to build it first and see if you can get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I think of, `self.view.makeToast()` is not expecting `style` parameter remove it and check or please check if you are calling makeToast() with correct parameters.

**UPDATE:**
Try this
1) Added dependency to Podfile 
2) Ran "pod install" 
3) Launch project by clicking `.xcworkspace` file
4) Build the project "cmd+B"
5) Added "import Toast_Swift" to ViewController and check.

Comment: Hi Joe. I tried this but it seems that the issue has to do with loading the Toast pod. See my comments above. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am still getting error saying "cannot load underlying module for Toast_Swift"   :(

Comment: OK, can you try by clearing the derived data and then do a clean build, OR if it doesn't work - Clear derived data, do a pod install again and clean build.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "clearing the derived data". Can you explain?

Comment: Go to your Xcode preferences > Locations > Derived Data and click on little arrow to navigate to your Derived Data path and trash all the directory and files inside that, they are basically your old builds data